# How Can I Pass The Item Bound To A KoGrid Cell To The ViewModel

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, kogrid

**HTML:**

```
<div data-bind="koGrid: gridOptions" style="height:600px;border:solid 1px #ccc;"></div>
```

**JS:**

Column definitions:

```
{ field: 'orderCatalogUpdateID', cellTemplate: '<button data-bind="click: $userViewModel.removeItem">X</button>', displayName: ' ', width: '2%' }`
```

removeItem function on the ViewModel:

```
self.removeItem = function (item) {
    self.list.remove(item);
}
```

The `item` that gets passed to the `removeItem` function is not the data item that is bound to the row but rather the KoGrid column. How can I get the data item that is bound to the row so I can pass it to the `remove` function on the observable array?

I have tried wiring up click events with jQuery and a variety of cell templates trying to pass in the data item being bound to the row with no success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default the current datacontext gets passed to the `click` handler  which is the current column object as described in the [documentation](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/KoGrid/wiki/About-Custom-Templates):

> $data: kg.Column: //the column entity

What you need to pass in is the `$parent.entity: //your data model` which is the current row entity.

So you need to change your binding:

```
{ 
    field: 'orderCatalogUpdateID', 
    cellTemplate: '<button data-bind="click: ' + 
       ' function() { $userViewModel.removeItem($parent.entity); }">X</button>', 
    displayName: ' ', 
    width: '2%' 
}
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pPfLf/).